# Redirecting www.domain.com to domain.com with NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am getting duplicate URLs on crawls of my Django site via my SEO tools and via Google tools. I want to ditch [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) completely and redirect all traffic to domain.com

Below is my NGINX conf. Cerbot has added its https info. Curious what I’m doing wrong here.

```
server {


server_name domain.com;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
        root /root/domain/domain-django;
        }

location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
        server_name www.domain.com;
        return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {

    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbotserver
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving this config part to the very beginning of your config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Also there might exist some caches, even broken ones, so you might need time for them to expire